# trapezodial rule matlab

Tags: math, matlab

I want to integrate "\int_{0}^{1}(exp(-int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx))dy" with my basic trapezoid algorithm. I recieve an error declaration, but I should define g as a function. Do you have any idea  how to do it? 
Thanks a lot for any answer!

```
function y = trapapadbl(low1, up1,low2,up2,intstep1,intstep2,f)
g = 0;
step1 = (up1 - low1) / intstep1;
step2 = (up2 - low2) / intstep2;

for j = low1 : step1 : up1
    g = g + feval(f,j);
end
g = @(y)(g - (feval(f, low1) + feval(f, up1))/2) * step1;
for i = low2 : step2 : up2
    y= y + feval(g,i);
end
y= (y - (feval(g, low2) + feval(g, up2))/2) * step2;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example call?

Comment: Can you also display the error message?

Comment: tesekkurler @İsmail Arı:) What I want to evaluate is for example  int_{0}^{2}int_{0}^{y}exp(x)dx dy=? I have a poor experience on programming, but I think I probaly should define a function for inner integral. "How" is actually my question? tesekkürler tekrar...

Comment: f=@(x)x^2

f = 

    @(x)x^2

>> trapapadbl(0, 1,2,3,10,10,f)
??? Undefined function or variable "y".

Error in ==> trapapadbl at 18
    y= y + feval(g,i);

Answer (score 2):

```
>> trapapadbl(0,1,0.1,0,1,0.1,@sin)

??? Undefined function or variable "y".

Error in ==> trapapadbl at 12
    y= y + feval(g,i);
```

Without working too hard to try to understand your code (!) the error is that `y` was never initialized.  You can't add anything to `y` until it has a value.  When I initialize `y` to 0, the code runs, but I get `0` as an output, which is not what happens when you integrate `sin` from 0 to 1.  I may be calling the function wrong, but it's something to look out for!

Furthermore, your code is confusing, because you use the variable `g` as both a double (a number) and a function, even in the same line!  The same problem happens as `y` is the input to your anonymous function, but also a double later on.  It's syntactically correct, but a little hard to read.  Consider using a different variable name, or including clear comments (or both!)

Comment: thank you @alexplanation! Now I found my question also a bit confusing:)